# How to mark JIRA status "Closed" when Current status of JIRA issue is "Resolved" via REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

Current jira status is "Resolved" and trying to close it with "transition":{"id":"2"}, "update":{"comment":""} getting error Can't move (DC-XXXXXX). You might not have permission, or the issue is missing required information. If you keep having this problem, contact your JIRA Administrator."

Note: current status of jira is "Resolved"

```
https://continuum.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/issue/DC-102/transitions

{
   "transition":{"id":"2"},
   "update":{"comment":[{"add":{"body":"Auto close the issue"}}]}
}
```

Comment: Does your workflow allows the transition?

Comment: Can you with this user do this transition in web ui?

Comment: This is likely a workflow issue - make sure that a) there is a transition from Resolved to Closed, and that b) any fields required for that transition have been filled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by changing the id to 701

Note: Ensure transition from Resolved to Closed required 701 id value.

https://continuum.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/DC-xxxxxx/transitions?expand=transitions.fields

```
{
   "transition":{"id":"701"},
   "update":{"comment":[{"add":{"body":"Auto Comment added to close issue"}}]}
 }
```